# Horizontal Bar Chart: how to add X-Bar Axis Labels

Tags: ios, swift, charts

Here I am using [Charts Library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) 
For Horizontal Bar chart , 
i have set code as below

```
var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {

    let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), yValues: [values[i]])

          dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
}

let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")

let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
barChartView.data = chartData

       //Horizontal

        HbarChartView.animate(yAxisDuration: 0.2)
        HbarChartView.data = chartData
        HbarChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        HbarChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.blue
        HbarChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .easeInBounce)
        HbarChartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(ll)
        HbarChartView.setVisibleYRange(minYRange: 0, maxYRange: 10, axis: .left)
```

X-Axis data is in blue.

I want to set String on X-Axis. How can i do this?

Any help is Appreciated

[image]

Or else,
Suggest any other Chart Library for Horizontal Bar including **Bar Value** and **Animation**

Comment: add a link to the Charts Library

Comment: Link: **https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts**
from which i have download Chart Library

Comment: i think you need to write your own [IAxisValueFormatter](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=IAxisValueFormatter)

Comment: This is used to convert Double value to String.
But in my demo i want to show Months on xAxis.

Comment: look for the DayAxisValueFormatter

Comment: I am not getting any idea. How can i use DayAxisValueFormatter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement [IAxisValueFormatter](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/Source/Charts/Formatters/IAxisValueFormatter.swift) in your own classes:

for this you need only to implement this method:

```
func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String
```

Examples:

- [DefaultAxisValueFormatter](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/Source/Charts/Formatters/DefaultAxisValueFormatter.swift) -> here you can use a block to add your custom calculation
- [IndexAxisValueFormatter](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/Source/Charts/Formatters/IndexAxisValueFormatter.swift)
- [LargeValueFormatter](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/ChartsDemo/Classes/Formatters/LargeValueFormatter.swift)

or you follow the [RayWenderlich Tutorial "Using Realm and Charts with Swift 3 in iOS 10"](https://medium.com/@skoli/using-realm-and-charts-with-swift-3-in-ios-10-40c42e3838c0#.iplbpj4ba):

you have to set some delegates and more but this is the key code snippet for a custom formatter:

```
// MARK: axisFormatDelegate
extension ViewController: IAxisValueFormatter {

  func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = “HH:mm.ss”
    return dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value))
  }
}
```